# Intellisense not working for packages with Ionide in VSCode

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, ionide

I am just beginning with FSharp and am trying to work in VSCode on my mac. I've followed all the install instructions here https://github.com/dotnet/netcorecli-fsc/wiki/.NET-Core-SDK-1.0.1

However Inoide can't seem to pick up any of the packages I've added. Here is an example:

[image: Screenshot of error]

As you can see the plugin is running ok as I get type info but it won't pick up the package. Hovering on the red squiggly shows the error `The namespace of module 'FsUnit' is not defined`

I'm running dotnetcore 1.0.3 and inoide-fsharp 2.25.10

Comment: Perhaps try submitting a GitHub issue on Ionide vscode extension repo

Comment: Furthermore, I am running the same setup and do not experience this.

Comment: Have you restarted VS Code since you ran `dotnet restore`? Ionide won't pick up the packages until you do, in my experience.

Comment: Yeah no luck after a restart of vscode. 

I have opened the issue on github 
https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/421. 

Thanks